# Laravel PHP - Have the the set option in db to be the selected in select list

Tags: php, laravel

I select two records from the database:

```
    return view('customers')->with(
        [
            "customers" => DB::table('people')
                ->leftJoin("statuses", "people.status", "=", "statuses.id")
                ->where('type', 'customer')
                ->get()->toArray(),
            "statuses"  => DB::table("statuses")->get()->toArray()
        ]);
```

Each `customer` has a `status` column that represents a `statuses.id`.

Now in my view:

```
                            @foreach ($customers as $customer)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$customer->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$customer->first_name}} {{$customer->last_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$customer->country_id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$customer->phone_number}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$customer->created_at}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$customer->email}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$customer->campaign}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select>
                                            @foreach($statuses as $status)
                                                <option>{{$status->title}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

I print all of the statuses, but I want to set the selected status to be the ID that I joined with `people`

What is the best practice to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check the customer status against the status id

```
  <select>
     @foreach($statuses as $status)
        <option @if($customer->status == $status->id) selected="selected" @endif>{{$status->title}}</option>
     @endforeach
  </select>
```